# .htaccess to create SEO url not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the file path: example.com/blog/ where blog is a directory. Blog gets a query string from the URL called URL and makes a dynamic page out of that information. So essentially it's something like this: example.com/blog?url=hello-world but i'd like to remove the ?url part and instead add a slash. So it should look something like this: example.com/blog/hello-world I've tried to accomplish this by putting the .htaccess file in the blog directory. This is my current .htaccess file, but it is not working:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stories/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?url=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Inside /blog there is a index.php file and that generates the dynamic page.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    blog/index.php?url=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^blog/?$    blog/index.php    [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is still not working for some reason. I have the .htaccess file inside the /blog directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

**EDIT**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(blog)/(.*)$ blog/index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: This is what I have currently in my .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/haDCy2cm When I go to example.com/blog/hello-world it is returning a 404, when it should return a page

Comment: This is still not working. I accidentally put the wrong directory, it should be RewriteBase /blog/ this was my fault sorry, but even when I change the directory name to the correct one, it's still not working. Also, the .htaccess file is inside /blog and the file that creates the dynamic page is index.php so essentially it's this: example.com/blog/index.php?url=hello-world

Comment: I tried both ways, but still both don't work for some reason